# Hugo fails to build site, saying it is unable to find a theme

Tags: gitlab, hugo

I am trying to deploy a hugo website on Gitlab but it returns the following error:

```
WARN: 2016/11/04 14:57:24 hugo.go:547: Unable to find static directory for theme strange-case in /builds/joaoeira/hugo/themes/strange-case/static
```

The theme "strange-case" is inside the themes folder, and it has a static folder there which is why I am finding this problem baffling. Here I include the steps I took to deploy the website (it says github because that was my first try):

```
git submodule add https://github.com/ExchangeRate-API/strange-case.git
git remote add origin https://github.com/joaoeira/joaoeira.github.io.git
hugo -t strange-case
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push origin master
```

The final message hugo gives me:

```
=============================================================
Your rendered home page is blank: /index.html is zero-length
* Did you specify a theme on the command-line or in your
"config.toml" file? (Current theme: "strange-case")
* For more debugging information, run "hugo -v"
=============================================================
```

Any guesses?

My config.toml file:

```
baseurl = "https://joaoeira.gitlab.io"
title = "Lettuce be Cereal"
author = "João Eira"
copyright = "Your Copyright"
canonifyurls = true
paginate = 5
PygmentsCodeFences = false

googleAnalytics = ""

contentdir = "content/post"
layoutdir = "layouts"
publishdir = "public"
theme = "strange-case"

[params]
    colorScheme = "scheme-darkbrown"
    DateFormat = "2 Jan 2006"
    description ="João Eira is a Master's student in Economics at Universidade de Coimbra."
    sidebarDescription = "João Eira's personal blog"
    sidebarFreeText =  "\"Shared fictions are the necessary condition of social coordination.\""
    piwikSiteID = ""
    piwikURL = ""


[[menu.main]]
    name = "About"
    url = "http://joaoeira.com"

[[menu.main]]
    name = "Twitter"
    url = "http://twitter.com/joaoeira"
```

My .gitlab.ci.yml file. Note the "hugo -t strange-case -v" specifying the theme and all:

```
image: alpine:3.4

before_script:
  - apk update && apk add openssl
  - wget https://github.com/spf13/hugo/releases/download/v0.16/hugo_0.16_linux-64bit.tgz
  - echo "37ee91ab3469afbf7602a091d466dfa5  hugo_0.16_linux-64bit.tgz" | md5sum -c
  - tar xf hugo_0.16_linux-64bit.tgz && cp ./hugo /usr/bin
  - hugo version

test:
  script:
  - hugo
  except:
  - master

pages:
  script:
  - hugo -t strange-case -v
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: The submodule was causing problems in my case. Convert the submodule to a normal (non-git) folder by removing the .git folder from the root folder of the theme. Does it solver your problem?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this since?

Answer (score 1):

## Possible Solution

> (!) Make sure to update your `baseUrl` in hugo's config.toml

In my case, hugo was rendering fine locally, but not working when I deployed to gitlab pages.

## How I got the error

Originally, I had my theme (ananke) installed in the correct place (`repo/thems/ananke`) according to the Hugo Quickstart. But, when my site didn't render on gitlab pages, I tried moving the module into publicc because I was afraid it wasn't available to the deployment. That's when I got the same error as the OP above.

But, when set my `baseUrl` to match the url provided by gitlab pages (and moved my them back into the top level `themes` directory) everything worked. :)

## Disclaimer

YMMV, but in the end the `baseUrl` was all I was missing. Everything else I learned from the Hugo quickstart and hugo tutorial on deploying to gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was with submodules. Submodules must me mentioned using relative url in **.gitmodules**. Also variable `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY` must be set to `recursive` in **.gitlab-ci.yml**.

To do it I forked theme in my namespace and used next config.

**.gitmodules**:

```
[submodule "themes/hugo-universal-theme"]
path = themes/hugo-universal-theme
url = ../hugo-universal-theme.git
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
# All available Hugo versions are listed here: https://gitlab.com/pages/hugo/container_registry
image: registry.gitlab.com/pages/hugo:latest

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

pages:
  script:
  - hugo
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you shouldn't need to fork a theme unless you're really trying to maintain differences from the original. Meanwhile, how did this work in your local testing? Did you have to have the forked theme next to your (website) repo on your computer as well as your gitlab account?