# React router No Match 404 not working when deployed?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, netlify

I added a No Match 404 error page to my website, and it works fine when I go to the wrong path on localhost, but after I deploy and go to an invalid path like .../invalidpath I get the default netlify page not found error. Below is my App.js component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from './components/navigation/Navigation';
import Home from './pages/home/Home';
import Projects from './pages/projects/Projects';
import Contact from './pages/contact/Contact';
import NoMatch from './pages/404page/404Page';

import './App.scss';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/projects' component={Projects} />
        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
        <Route path='*' component={NoMatch} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you tried *not* specifying a `path` for your 404 route? This is the more typical way of defining a 404 route. I don't know if it'll effect netlify however.

Comment: Yeah I tried it without the path and still wouldn’t work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've built the app with `create-react-app` and you're deploying to Netlify, you need to add a `_redirects` file inside the `public` directory of your project in order to support client side routing (React Router). It should have this inside:

```
/*  /index.html  200
```

Details [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#netlify).
Also, check the official docs from Netlify regarding for [Redirects and rewrites](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/)

Comment: the website you linked says the file should be called `_redirects`, however it still doesnt work for me

Comment: Try re-deploying the app to Netlify @notacorn that should publish the latest changes.

Comment: this was the answer for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/69901140/8652920