# Astro SSR webiste deploy failed on Netlify (prerendering static routes error)

Tags: deployment, netlify, astrojs

this Astro project was already deployed on Netlify without SSR and working just fine.

Once I changed it to SSR and tried a new build I got this error.

```
9:48:06 AM: 08:48:06 AM [build] output target: server
9:48:06 AM: 08:48:06 AM [build] deploy adapter: @astrojs/netlify/functions
9:48:06 AM: 08:48:06 AM [build] Collecting build info...
9:48:06 AM: 08:48:06 AM [build] Completed in 1.47s.
9:48:06 AM: 08:48:06 AM [build] Building server entrypoints...
9:48:09 AM: 08:48:09 AM [build] Completed in 3.11s.
9:48:09 AM: 
9:48:09 AM:  building client 
9:48:10 AM: Completed in 1.30s.
9:48:10 AM: 
9:48:10 AM: 
9:48:10 AM:  prerendering static routes 
9:48:10 AM:  error   Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
9:48:10 AM:   File:
9:48:10 AM:     /opt/build/repo/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/generate.js:66:20
9:48:10 AM:   Code:
9:48:10 AM:     65 |   const ssrEntryURL = new URL("./" + serverEntry + `?time=${Date.now()}`, outFolder);
9:48:10 AM:     > 66 |   const ssrEntry = await import(ssrEntryURL.toString());
9:48:10 AM:          |                    ^
9:48:10 AM:       67 |   const builtPaths = /* @__PURE__ */ new Set();
9:48:10 AM:       68 |   if (opts.settings.config.output === "server") {
9:48:10 AM:       69 |     for (const pageData of eachPrerenderedPageData(internals)) {
9:48:10 AM:   Stacktrace:
9:48:10 AM: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
9:48:10 AM:     at file:///opt/build/repo/.netlify/functions-internal/chunks/pages/all.bcf310be.mjs:1556:17
9:48:10 AM:     at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
9:48:10 AM:     at async Promise.all (index 0)
9:48:11 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
9:48:10 AM:     at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)
9:48:10 AM:     at async generatePages (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/generate.js:66:20)
9:48:10 AM:     at async staticBuild (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/static-build.js:85:7)
9:48:10 AM:     at async AstroBuilder.build (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/index.js:122:5)
9:48:10 AM:     at async AstroBuilder.run (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/index.js:153:7)
9:48:10 AM:     at async build (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/index.js:37:3)
9:48:10 AM:     at async runCommand (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/astro/dist/cli/index.js:168:14)
9:48:10 AM:     at async cli (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/astro/dist/cli/index.js:203:5)
9:48:10 AM: ​
9:48:10 AM:   "build.command" failed
```

I checked multiple times on the Astro and Netlify docs if I missed something but it doesn't seem to be the case.
Astro.config:

```
import netlify from "@astrojs/netlify/functions";

output: 'server',
adapter: netlify()
```

On Netlify I activated prerendering in Site settings > Build & deploy > Post processing > Prerendering.

Answer (score 0):

I share what worked for me if you still need the answer, Astro SSR webiste deploy requires an adapter that matches your deployment runtime, Add the Node adapter to enable SSR in your Astro projec, install the adapter manually:

npm install @astrojs/node

Then edit your astro.config.mjs

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import node from '@astrojs/node';

export default defineConfig({
  output: 'server',
  adapter: node({
    mode: 'standalone'
  }),
});
```

Deploy again yout Astro SSR webiste on Netlify, If for some reason it doesn't work with this change, please try again by adding these additional lines to your file defineConfig({}).

```
vite: {
    ssr: {
      noExternal: ["solid-use", "@xstate/svelte",'whatwg-url']
    }
},
```

resources that were helpful:
https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/node/#configuration
useful for after deploy:
["Page Not Found" when trying to access a site deployed on Netlify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752350/page-not-found-when-trying-to-access-a-site-deployed-on-netlify)